# Cannot build cordova project; breaking after xcode 7.0 update (from iOS9)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

The project was able to build and run before I updated xcode to the latest (with support for iOS9).

Now I'm getting the following on `cordova build ios --verbose`:

`Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -
xcconfig,/Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,ProjectName.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,ProjectName,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Command finished with error code 2: /Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build 
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/lunchbag/ProjectName/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/lunchbag/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)`

I've tried cleaning the project and remove and re-adding the ios platform. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. The clue was in the XCode error logs. The culprit was the Keyboard plugin. Remove and re-add and it shall build once again :)

Comment: would of been a better answer with a description

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reinstall the keyboard plugin, but this did not solve the issue. Then I found this http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/10/23/getting-an-error-running-a-cordova-project-to-ios

Turns out you need to run the new Xcode 7 once and accept the license agreement.